# trying to parse an xml data from a web service .SAXParseException

Tags: android, xml, parsing, android-studio, xml-parsing

I am attempting to parse a data document from open weather app. I am successfully reading in the entire file. I can put that entire file into a text view. I just need to parse that data. I get this error when I try to parse:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Unexpected end of document

Here is my code for parse and reading the document in.

```
public void Weather(View view){
    InputStream data;
    final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API =
            "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=";

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    try {
        URL url = new URL(String.format(OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API + City + "&mode=xml&appid=40f9dad632ecd4d87b55cb512d538b75"));
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // connection.addRequestProperty("x-api-key", this.getString(R.string.open_weather_maps_app_id));

        data = connection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(data);
        BufferedReader Reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);


        StringBuffer Weatherdata = new StringBuffer();
        String storage;
        while ((storage = Reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Weatherdata.append(storage + "\n");

        }
        cityField.setText(Weatherdata.toString());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        cityField.setText("Fail");
        return;
    }
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documetBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documetBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(data);
        Element rootElement = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I did a quick google search the other person who had this error was having this error when he had the file stored on the computer/phone.

Answer (score 0):

It occurs because you already reach the end of the `InputStream` when trying to parse your xml.
Indeed, when displaying the stream content using the `InputStreamReader` you move the file "cursor" until the end of the stream.

So, when you try to parse it with the SAX parser, it raises this end of document Exception (if you replace the parsing code to a call to data.read(), it will return -1 which means that you already reach the end of the stream).

If you remove the `InputStreamReader` related code, you will be able to parse the xml.

If you want to keep this code, since the `reset` method (which allows to reset the cursor to the beginning of the file) is not supported on `HttpInputStream` you should copy its content to a `StringBuilder` or a `BufferedInputStream` for example.